# How can I do nested query Symfony2 and show results on template?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm newbie with Symfony2 and Doctrine.

I have a query:

```
SELECT
    `Citta`.`value`, `User`.`slug`, `User`.`nome`, `Photo`.`value`, `User`.`slogan`
FROM `table1`.`users` AS `User`
LEFT JOIN `table1`.`photos` AS `Photo` ON (`Photo`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `table1`.`cittas` AS `Citta` ON (`Citta`.`id` = `User`.`citta_id`)
WHERE `User`.`attivo` = 1
GROUP BY `User`.`id`
ORDER BY `User`.`id` desc
```

I want to put it into my `indexAction` in the default controller because I want to show in home the name, the picture and the city of a user.

With

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users');
$users = $repository->findAll();
```

I can find all the users and I can show their names on the page.

But how can I retrieve all of the other data?

Answer (score 3):

When using the `findAll()` function provided by Doctrine, you can use the helper functions that are generated in the entity:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users');
$users = $repo->findAll();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $photos = $user->getPhotos();
    $cittas = $user->getCittas();
    // do stuff with the variables
}
```

If you're trying to order the results of the User objects in a meaningful manner such as descending by User ID:

```
$users = $repo->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC')); // first array() is for select portions
```

If you're trying to replicate the raw SQL query (which I'm not sure would even execute), you would use the `find()` method:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users');
$users = $repo->find(1); // 1 is the User ID

$photos = $user->getPhotos();
$cittas = $user->getCittas();
// do stuff...
```

Since you're finding a single entry in this scenario, the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are unnecessary.

**Note that this answer assumes that you have correctly set up all of your ORM Entities correctly with Doctrine and their respective X-to-Y associations.**

Comment: I think ORM Entities are ok. I used the Many-To-One, Unidirectional (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)
But I think that the built array ($cittas) is not empty because I inserted "if cittas is not defined" into the template and nothing appears. I use the "foreach" like first example. how can display the value into the template?

Comment: I print dump(citta) on template and values's array are null